# Is there a way to edit HomePageView UIElements such as Textblocks inside the OnLoading() function of SplashScreen of WinUIEx?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I've implemented WinUIEx SplashScreen capability to my WinUI 3 program by following this [guide](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx/blob/main/docs/concepts/Splashscreen.md) and I successfully do some checks and assignments in the beginning of the program. I wonder if there is a way to load the entire app while this SplashScreen is on the screen.

Since on some pages there are some data being retrieved and parsed after that page is opened for the first time by using `HomePageView.Loaded()` event, if these could be loaded while SplashScren is on the screen, the responsiveness and UX of the App would increase significantly.

I thought of doing most of the data loading/parsing within the `OnLoading()` method of the SplashScreen however I do UI updates and for example if there is an error, use `ContentDialog()` to inform user etc. and since these pages are not static and called before being navigated to I could not find a solution. If there is a way to load these pages while splash screen is on the user screen so that when the splash screen closes and program is on front, the pages would be responsive right from the beginning.

Are there any ways to achieve this kind of behaviour? How can I change structure of my program so that I can get the App loaded upfront?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `Func` and show the splash screen and do loadings in the background:

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace WinUIExSamples;

public partial class App : Application
{
    private Window? window;

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        TextService textService = new();
        List<string> textList = new();

        SplashScreen splash = new(
            window: typeof(MainWindow),
            task: new Func<IProgress<int>, Task>(async (progress) =>
            {
                // Loading work here.
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    string text = await textService.GetText(i + 1);
                    textList.Add(text);
                    progress.Report(i * 10);
                }

                progress.Report(100);
            }));

        splash.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e is not null)
            {
                // Pass the loading results to the MainPage here.
                e.Content = new MainPage(textList);
            }
            this.window = e;
        };
    }
}
```

**SplashScreen.xaml**

```xml
<winuiex:SplashScreen
    x:Class="WinUIExSamples.SplashScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUIExSamples"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:winuiex="using:WinUIEx"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel
        Margin="10"
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Run Text="{x:Bind ProgressBar.Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Run Text="/" />
            <Run Text="{x:Bind ProgressBar.Maximum, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

</winuiex:SplashScreen>
```

**SplashScreen.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace WinUIExSamples;

public sealed partial class SplashScreen : WinUIEx.SplashScreen
{
    private Func<IProgress<int>, Task> task;

    public SplashScreen(Type window, Func<IProgress<int>, Task> task) : base(window)
    {
        this.task = task;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async Task OnLoading()
    {
        Progress<int> progress = new();
        progress.ProgressChanged += Progress_ProgressChanged;
        await task.Invoke(progress);
    }

    private void Progress_ProgressChanged(object? sender, int e)
    {
        this.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
        {
            this.ProgressBar.Value = e;
        });
    }
}
```

**TextService.cs**

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace WinUIExSamples;

public class TextService
{
    public async Task<string> GetText(int textId)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return $"Text#{textId}";
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUIExSamples.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUIExSamples"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind TextList, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace WinUIExSamples;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> TextList { get; set; }

    public MainPage(List<string> textList)
    {
        TextList = new(textList);
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going over this answer and didn't quite understand what you are doing. With this method can you update data in for example HomePage AND PageExample2? Also I didn't understand what TextList is doing? Maybe I should post my structure please I'm little bit lost in this answer sorry.

Comment: I've made actually an update to this. I re-read your code several times and at the end, what I did was that I created a static Dictionary where I set dictionary keys same as the item names (like HomePageViewTextBlock1) then do startup operations like getting data from internet, parsing localsettings and few other operations. Then inside constructor of the pages I just assign the variables from the Dictionary (since the heavy computing part is already done during startup).

Comment: To answer your question, the TextList is just a part of this sample code to show how you can retrieve data from a service, the TextService in this case, and pass the data to a page. All of this work can be done by passing a ``Func`` to the ``SplashScreen``.